# python opencv display time countdown using putText in webcam video

Tags: python, opencv, time

**Aim:**

I'd like to put text on each frame obtained by the webcam so that the text "3", "2", "1" can be displayed for a second each. Thus portraying a countdown timer. Following the countdown, a frame should be written to file i.e. saved to disk. This should be repeatable as long as the video stream has not been closed.

Each frame is obtained within a while loop and due to hardware configuration the camera may have an unknown frame rate or worse, the number of frames retrieved by the camera per second can vary during the course of running the camera.

`time.sleep()` cannot be used because it freezes the while loop and disrupts the video stream being displayed in the window.

another while loop inside the main while loop is unacceptable because it slows down the processor greatly and fewer frames are processed per second making the video stream very choppy.

**What I've tried:**

```
import cv2
import sys
import time

# Initialize variables
camSource = -1
running = True
saveCount = 0
nSecond = 1
totalSec = 3.0
keyPressTime = 0.0
startTime = 0.0
timeElapsed = 0.0
startCounter = False
endCounter = False

# Start the camera
camObj = cv2.VideoCapture(camSource)
if not camObj.isOpened():
    sys.exit('Camera did not provide frame.')

frameWidth = int(camObj.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frameHeight = int(camObj.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Start video stream
while running:
    readOK, frame = camObj.read()

    # Display counter on screen before saving a frame
    if startCounter:
        if nSecond <= totalSec: 
            # draw the Nth second on each frame 
            # till one second passes  
            cv2.putText(img = frame, 
                        text = str(nSecond),
                        org = (int(frameWidth/2 - 20),int(frameHeight/2)), 
                        fontFace = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 
                        fontScale = 3, 
                        color = (255,0,0),
                        thickness = 2, 
                        lineType = cv2.CV_AA)

            timeElapsed += (time.time() - startTime)
            print 'timeElapsed:{}'.format(timeElapsed)

            if timeElapsed >= 1:
                nSecond += 1
                print 'nthSec:{}'.format(nSecond)
                timeElapsed = 0
                startTime = time.time()

        else:
            # Save the frame
            cv2.imwrite('img' + str(saveCount) + '.jpg', frame)  
            print 'saveTime: {}'.format(time.time() - keyPressTime)

            saveCount += 1
            startCounter = False
            nSecond = 1

    # Get user input
    keyPressed = cv2.waitKey(3)
    if keyPressed == ord('s'):
        startCounter = True
        startTime = time.time()
        keyPressTime = time.time()
        print 'startTime: {}'.format(startTime)
        print 'keyPressTime: {}'.format(keyPressTime)

    elif keyPressed == ord('q'):
        # Quit the while loop
        running = False
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Show video stream in a window    
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)

camObj.release()
```

**Problem:**

I can see that my method almost works but the cpu ticks returned by `time.time()` is not the same as real world seconds. The text for each numeral isn't displayed for a whole second and the file is saved too quickly (within 1.5 seconds instead of 3).

**I'll accept as an answer:**

If you can show how to get the timing correct and how to display "3", "2", "1" instead of my current method which displays "1", "2", "3"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After struggling for two days and reading up on `datetime` module I have what I need. I can however accept an answer other than mine if it is more pythonic.

```
import cv2
import sys
from datetime import datetime

# Initialize variables
camSource = -1
running = True
saveCount = 0
nSecond = 0
totalSec = 3
strSec = '321'
keyPressTime = 0.0
startTime = 0.0
timeElapsed = 0.0
startCounter = False
endCounter = False

# Start the camera
camObj = cv2.VideoCapture(camSource)
if not camObj.isOpened():
    sys.exit('Camera did not provide frame.')

frameWidth = int(camObj.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
frameHeight = int(camObj.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Start video stream
while running:
    readOK, frame = camObj.read()

    # Display counter on screen before saving a frame
    if startCounter:
        if nSecond < totalSec: 
            # draw the Nth second on each frame 
            # till one second passes  
            cv2.putText(img = frame, 
                        text = strSec[nSecond],
                        org = (int(frameWidth/2 - 20),int(frameHeight/2)), 
                        fontFace = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 
                        fontScale = 6, 
                        color = (255,255,255),
                        thickness = 5, 
                        lineType = cv2.CV_AA)

            timeElapsed = (datetime.now() - startTime).total_seconds()
#            print 'timeElapsed: {}'.format(timeElapsed)

            if timeElapsed >= 1:
                nSecond += 1
#                print 'nthSec:{}'.format(nSecond)
                timeElapsed = 0
                startTime = datetime.now()

        else:
            cv2.imwrite('img' + str(saveCount) + '.jpg', frame)  
#            print 'saveTime: {}'.format(datetime.now() - keyPressTime)

            saveCount += 1
            startCounter = False
            nSecond = 1

    # Get user input
    keyPressed = cv2.waitKey(3)
    if keyPressed == ord('s'):
        startCounter = True
        startTime = datetime.now()
        keyPressTime = datetime.now()
#        print 'startTime: {}'.format(startTime)
#        print 'keyPressTime: {}'.format(keyPressTime)

    elif keyPressed == ord('q'):
        # Quit the while loop
        running = False
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Show video stream in a window    
    cv2.imshow('video', frame)

camObj.release()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version of my own implementation of seemless dispay of countdown timer of five seconds before a 10 seconds video output for whatever! Please let me know any questions in comments!

```
    def draw_text(frame, text, x, y, color=(255,0,255), thickness=4, size=3):
            if x is not None and y is not None:
                cv2.putText(
                    frame, text, (int(x), int(y)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, size, color, thickness)

    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import time
    #timeout = time.time() + 11   # 10 seconds from now
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    init_time = time.time()
    test_timeout = init_time+6
    final_timeout = init_time+17
    counter_timeout_text = init_time+1
    counter_timeout = init_time+1
    counter = 5
    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret==True:
            center_x = int(frame.shape[0]/2)
            center_y = int(frame.shape[0]/2)
            if (time.time() > counter_timeout_text and time.time() < test_timeout):
                draw_text(frame, str(counter), center_x, center_y)
                counter_timeout_text+=0.03333
            if (time.time() > counter_timeout and time.time() < test_timeout):
                counter-=1
                counter_timeout+=1
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')) or (time.time() > final_timeout):
                break
        else:
            break
    # Release everything if job is finished
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: how did you come up with `counter_timeout_text+=0.03333`?

Comment: Goal is to draw on each frame. 1/(FPS)30

Comment: Drawing on the set of frames that last a second is the challenge. The FPS isn't constant and it isn't the same for different cameras.

Comment: you can set the fps while capturing